# Should I add 1 to my unknown string size when I create a char array to hold it via malloc?

Tags: array, malloc

When I have a string of unknown size and I create an char array to hold this string.

I do something like this:

```
 #define LINE_END "\r\n"

int line_end_size = strlen(LINE_END);
char line[]="Hello! world.";
int line_size=strlen(line);
int test_line_size=line_size+line_end_size;
char *test_line = malloc(test_line_size);
strcpy(test_line,line);
strcat(test_line,LINE_END);

printf("test_line = ");
int index;
for (index = 0; index<test_line_size+1; index++) /* plus 1 to see the null */
    printf("%02X ", (unsigned char)test_line[index]);
printf("\n");
```

Should I add 1 to the size of `test_line_size` to hold the NULL character?

This must be compiled for **linux32**, **win32**, **arm32**.

Comment: Ask yourself what will happen if you don't add room for that zero.

Comment: Would also like to point out that whenever you know the length of a C string you should be using the "mem*" functions instead. Like `memcpy()`. The "str*" functions are a waste of time, looking for the zero terminator when you already know the length.

Comment: oh, okay. I will read...

Comment: If I dont have the null the str functions will not know where the array ends... So 'I' must make room for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you treat it as a char array, then you don't need a 0 at the end. It's just an array like any other.

But if you want to use string functions on it (like the `strcpy`, `strcat` in your example), those will look for, rsp. add a null terminator at the end of your arrays, so you will need the reserved space for it!

Note that your `strcat` already writes this 0 past the end of the `malloc`'d space.

If you used the `mem...` functions (like @zan-lynx commented), and iterated the array without the `+1`, it'd be perfectly fine (if unusual).